# Traveling with a previous non-expired passport

Tags: visas, uk, passports, paperwork, peruvian-citizens

I renewed my non biometric passport two weeks ago. It expires in 2019.
So I now have two passports, a biometric one and a non biometric one. I'm traveling in a week and have to apply for a UK visa in 3 days.

Can I give my old passport for applying with my visa and travel with the new one? Can I use my old passport with my UK visa to travel ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you going, and what is your nationality?

Comment: Were both passports issued by the same country?

Comment: Did they mark something on the new passport? In Canada it would either have holes punched through it or a corner snipped which makes it invalid. I have no idea what they do to old UK passports though.

Comment: @Itai did you mean to ask whether they marked something on the *old* passport?

Comment: @Giorgio "renewed" indicates that the new passport was issued by the same country.

Comment: @Coke the need to apply for a UK visa indicates that the Adrien Neveu is going to the UK.  Since we know that, knowing the nationality won't add any useful information.

Comment: Passports are both Peruvians and both issued in Peru, nothing was marked on the old passport.

Comment: Are you sure it is whole, or was not stamped? For instance, passports are not valid without having all the pages on them, or without having at least two free pages.

Comment: I added a new detail in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise using the new passport on both situations, and to get the VISA on it.

Nowadays you can go or may be even required to go to electronic check-in queues when entering several countries. In other countries you may get faster though immigration using the biometric one.

Official might also do not like the old, non-biometric one. I was using one  3 years ago that was issued in an emergency, and when (re)entering *my own country* returning from a country known for being easy to get forged documents - and a top of that, the passport registered as being issued in yet another 3rd continent, I was questioned and required to answer in my own mother tongue to trow out initial suspicions I would be carrying a fake passport. Mind you that a *decade ago*, when I was issued that non-eletronic passport, I was warned not to use it for long, well, for it not being biometric.

Most countries also invalidate the old passport when issuing a new one to any individual, and in these post-computer days your old passport might be flagged as not a valid one, at least in the databases of your own country. When issued a new passport, normally you are not supposed to continue using the old one e.g. you are not supposed to have two active passports from the same country.

There might be a risk having your VISA refused using the old passport. I would use the new one, and would try the normal process and, if necessary, pay any required fees to speed up the process.

Also from a Peruvian travel agency site detailing the national passport legalities: [Tramites de Pasaporte Expedicion, Revalidacion y Anulacion](http://www.lepoint.com.pe/datos-utiles/visa-y-pasaporte/)

> ANULACIÓN DE PASAPORTES: Es automática y gratuita cuando se solicita
>   un nuevo pasaporte al mismo tiempo.

English Translation: "CANCELLATION OF PASSPORTS: It is automatic and free when a new passport is requested at the same time."